# C# list of list?

Tags: c#

If i have this:

```
List<List<int>> matrix = new List<List<int>>();
```

how would I populate it so it looks something like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 8):

```
List<List<int>> matrix = new List<List<int>>(new []{
                 new List<int>(new []{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}),
                 new List<int>(new []{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}),
                 new List<int>(new []{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0})});
```

---

Arnis L. here...

Just wanted to add that collection initializers might be used (if .Net 3.0 is supported):

```
var matrix = new List<List<int>>{
                 new List<int>{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                 new List<int>{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                 new List<int>{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
```

Comment: You mean C# 3.0, as collection initializers have nothing to do with .NET 3.0.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, how would you populate a single `List<int>` so that it contains zeroes?

You want to make up a bunch of those and then push them into the containing list.

Answer (score 4):

I really would avoid this for matrices. There is no way of ensuring that each sub list is the same length as the others. If its not dynamic then you should use multidimensional arrays

```
int[,] names = new int[7,3];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're making a matrix, why not use a [two-dimensional array](http://dotnetperls.com/2d-array-use)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to initialise the ragged list:

```
matrix =
  Enumerable.Repeat(0,3)
  .Select(d => Enumerable.Repeat(0,7).ToList())
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might not want to use lists for a matrix representation unless the matrix is really sparse...but how would you make a list of ints? Then once you had one of those, how would you add that to your list of lists? How many times do you need to add such lists to your list?

Answer (score 0):

And if it is sparse, consider using

```
int[][] matrix;
```

This is far more efficient in speed and memory footprint than using a List.

If you want some openly readable matrix functionality you might look at [Math.Net's Iridium project](http://iridium.mathdotnet.com). It supports sparse matrixes, and has a huge number of matrix functions.
Its implementation is only slightly slower than using Double[,], and I've used it for functions on matrixes with over 60,000,000 values.

Comment: No, it's not far more efficient. There is a bit of overhead for each List, but the List class uses an array as internal storage, so the difference is not that big.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the `int[,]` because it is much readable, for me at least...

Answer (score 0):

```
int rows;
int columns;
List<List<int>> matrix;

matrix = new List<List<int>>();
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    List<int> row;

    row = new List<int>();
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        row.Add(0);
    }

    matrix.Add(row);
}
```

If you want to place something else instead of "0" in the matrix, just replace the value that is added to the matrix row. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

i couldnt resist from asking, why dont you use a BitVector? is there a need to use list of list to have just binary sequences? or have chosen 0's and 1;s for example purpose?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32.aspx