# Multi-Dimensional Data Structures in C#

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

How do you create a multi-dimensional data structure in C#?

In my mind it works like so:

```
 List<List<int>> results = new List<List<int>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            results[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
```

This doesn't work (it throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`).  Is there a multi-dimensional structure in C# that allows me to access members through their indexes?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"?

Comment: Probably "throws an exception since the referenced element doesn't exist."

Comment: It crashes and says its out of range

Comment: I guess he's referring to the ArgumentOutOfRangeException that you get when you try to run the code.

Comment: That's the sort of thing that should be in your question. Please edit your question to add it.

Comment: I'd go for an array of arrays. You'll have to know the array size(s) up front, but there will actually be a "bucket" for each int when you instantiate the variable.

Comment: Why the second question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844090/c-list-of-list

Answer (score 10):

The problem here is that `List` doesn't automatically create elements. To initialise a `List<List<T>>` you need something like this:

```
List<List<int>> results = new List<List<int>>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    results.Add(new List<int>());
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        results[i].Add(0);
    }
}
```

Note that setting `Capacity` is not sufficient, you need to call `Add` the number of times you need. Alternatively, you can simplify things by using Linq's `Enumerable` class:

```
List<List<int>> results = new List<List<int>>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    results.Add(new List<int>());
    results[i].AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(0, 10));
}
```

Again, note that `Enumerable.Repeat(new List<int>(), 10)` will not work, since it will add 10 references to the same list.

Another approach using Linq to the extreme:

```
List<List<int>> results = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 10)
    .Select(i => Enumerable.Repeat(0, 10).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

(The unused parameter `i` is necessary to ensure that you don't reference the same list ten times as discussed above.)

Finally, to access elements, you can use exactly the notation you used before. Once the elements have been added, they can be read or modified as shown:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        results[i][j] = 2;
        int x = results[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, then you either include code to ensure you have enough elements already added before you access it, or you use `Dictionary<int,Dictionary<int,int>>`.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the dimensions of your structure in advance, and you do not plan to add or remove elements, then a 2D array sounds like your thing:

```
int[,] n = new int[10, 20];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
        n[i, j] = ...
    };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to create the lists and initialize them with zeros before you can't start indexing into them.

```
    List<List<int>> results = new List<List<int>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        results.Add(new List<int>(Enumerable.Repeat(0, 10)));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to actually 1) create each of the inner lists, and 2) set them to that size.

```
var Results = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => Enumerable.Repeat(0, 10).ToList()).ToList();
```

I'm a bit of a Linq addict, though.

Comment: Me too :-). This is my preferred way of doing it, so I added it into my answer as well. What's this `for` thing everyone keeps using? :o)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a datatable and add columns and rows? You would then be able to reference them by name or index.